# Google sheets - make a cell value static, print value in cell on edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, static, google-sheets

Really hard to explain but really easy question :

I want B46 to always contain the same value, even if rows are added or removed

I'm sure there's an easy script that would input the given value on edit but I'm not sure what to write

Thank you much in advance for your help!

Comment: This answer will almost certainly require a Google Apps script, so added that as a tag.

Comment: I guess no one has an answer...

Comment: @Cook Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample. each time your sheet is edit, the script will set the value on B46:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var value = /* Your value here */ ;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("B46").setValue(value);

}
```

Beware: The script does not modify the rest of the sheet to remove old values.

Example: If you add a row above row 46, the script will put the value on the new B46 cell, but will not delete the old one.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre-Marie Richard, that was exactly the expected result!
PS. Sorry for the late response, didn't see that coming!